# Install SSTP server on Windows 2008 (not R2). Possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sstp

I am trying to install RRAS on Windows 2008 (original Vista kernel version, not R2) in order to implement SSTP but after I configure RRAS, there is nothing in the security settings for setting the certificate. (First image link)

IIS is already installed and I have a self signed certificate installed there.  I've previously installed on another machine with  Windows2008 R2 and there is a place to set the certificate (second image link)

Does the original Vista based version of Windows2008 not support SSTP?  I can't find anywhere that says that.  If it is supported, what might I be missing?

[Windows2008 RRAS Properties No Cert select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqgIS.jpg)

[Windows2008 R2 RRAS Properties Cert Select Present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJA2V.jpg)

Comment: Don't think you'll get help on a product discontinued by Microsoft since Jan 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft *does* provide some documentation for deploying SSTP VPN in Windows Server 2008 but it is a bit different than newer versions of Windows Server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731352(v=ws.10).aspx#Configuring%20VPN1

The part that you really need to know is:

### Install Routing and Remote Access

Configure VPN1 with Routing and Remote Access to function as a VPN server.

Install VPN and certificate services roles

1. On VPN1, in the **Initial Configuration Tasks** window, under **Customize
   This Server**, click **Add roles**.
2. In the **Add Roles Wizard** dialog box, in **Before You Begin**, click **Next**.
3. Select the **Network Policy and Access Services** check box, click **Next**,
   and then click **Next** again.
4. In the **Select Role Services** dialog box, under **Role services**, select
   the **Routing and Remote Access Services** check box.
5. Click **Next**, and then click **Install**.
6. In the **Installation Results** dialog box, click **Close**.

### Configure Routing and Remote Access

Configure VPN1 to be a VPN server providing remote access for Internet-based VPN clients.

Configure VPN1 to be a VPN server

1. On VPN1, click **Start**, point to **Administrative Tools**, and then click **Routing and Remote Access**.
2. In the **Routing and Remote Access** console tree, right-click **VPN1**, and
   then click **Configure and Enable Routing and Remote Access**.
3. In the **Welcome to the Routing and Remote Access Server Setup Wizard**
   page, click **Next**.
4. In the **Configuration** page, click **Next** to accept the default setting
   of **Remote access (dial-up or VPN)**.
5. In the **Remote Access** page, click **VPN**, and then click **Next**.
6. In the **VPN Connection** page, under **Network interfaces**, click **Public**.
   This is the interface that will connect VPN1 to the Internet.
7. Click **Enable security on the selected interface by setting up static
   packet filters** to clear this setting, and then click **Next**.

> Normally, you would leave security enabled on the public interface. For the purposes of testing lab connectivity, you should
>   disable it.

8. Click **From a specified range of addresses**, and then click **Next**.
9. Click **New**, type **192.168.0.200** for the **Start IP address**, type **192.168.0.210** for the **End IP address**, click **OK**, and then click **Next**.
10. Click **Next** to accept the default setting, which means VPN1 will not
    work with a RADIUS server. In this scenario, Routing and Remote
    Access Server will use Windows Authentication.
11. In the **Completing the Routing and Remote Access Server Setup Wizard**
    page, click Finish.
12. If the dialog box that describes the need to add this computer to
    the remote access server list appears, click **OK**.
13. In the dialog box that describes the need to configure the DHCP
    Relay Agent, click **OK**.
14. Close the Routing and Remote Access snap-in.

You may want to overview the whole part for **Configuring VPN1** for the certificates part so you can make sure you are adding your certificates properly.

Hope this helps!